# CAKeyframeAnimation scale

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

I wan't to resize an UIView using keyframeAnimation because it has to be synced animated with a label text as it goes down.

So I've setup the size animation

```
        let sizeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        sizeAnimation.duration = 1.2

        let animationTime = TimeInterval(1.2/Float(volumeObjects.count - 1))
        // Stride is an inverted for in, it goes from volumeObjects count to 0

        var sizeAnimationValuesArray = [NSValue]()
        var keyTimes = [NSNumber]()
        var currentKeyTime: TimeInterval = 0
        for index in stride(from: volumeObjects.count - 1, to: -1, by: -1) {

            let currentPercentage = CGFloat(index)/CGFloat(volumeObjects.count)
            sizeAnimationValuesArray.append(NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, currentPercentage, 1.0)))
            keyTimes.append(NSNumber(value: currentKeyTime))
            currentKeyTime += animationTime
        }
        sizeAnimation.values = sizeAnimationValuesArray

        self.indicatorView.layer.add(sizeAnimation, forKey: "Bottom")
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work, literally nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually using the `keyTimes` array for anything. You populated it with times, but you didn't assign it to the animation.